# SDL Tridion 2011 UI - Server Errors when loading

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

When loading the new Tridion UI page the following errors appear in the message center.

/WebUI/Models/SiteEdit/Services/Services.svc/GetSiteEditItemConfiguration failed to execute.

/WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/General.svc/GetTridionWebSchema failed to execute.

/WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/Blueprinting.svc/LoadBlueprintInfo failed to execute.

These are the full errors.

The client has a 'Single Sign On' system provided by 'Siteminder'. We need to login to show popups and for the bootstrap.apsx to load. Could this be causing the above errors. If so how do I integrate Tridion UI with Single Sign On?

Content Manager Server Details:
Tridion 2011 SP1 Hotfix Rollup 1
Operating system: Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1
Web and Application server: Microsoft IIS 7.5
.NET Framework Microsoft: .NET Framework 4.0
Java: Java SE 6.0

Content Delivery Server Details:
Linux
Tomcat

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/concept_59979CAA10334D61979C34C85FA7703A

Comment: That's great thanks. Could not find that for looking. I have passed it onto the client's IT team to implement.

Answer (score 1):

First let's check if everything else is fine. Can you check if you can access CoreService? Navigate your browser to

```
/webservices/CoreService.svc
```

If you are able to get to CoreService page than it's most probably something wrong with CME itself. Check if it has Anonymous authentication and walk over all of the `web.config`s in the folders under Tridion\Web and check that you have followed all of the directions given in comments.